# Taming the beast

Tags: riddle

```
A wild cacophony of sound greets the arrival of this beast 
Perhaps you thought there'd be applause, a jovial shout should be the least

But fleeting glances, nostrils flared, each face curled slightly in a frown,
As all who share the journey know the beast is also going down.
```

What is the name of this beast?

Bonus points: Where is it?

Edit:
A final couplet as a hint:

> So try to banish this disgrace, light a candle, wave a fan,
>  Smear with incense, hide your face, or get out early, while you can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the "final couplet", it seems obvious that

> The "beast" is a fart.
> It arrives with a "wild cacophony of sound", and for some reason "you", the emitter, hoped it would be greeted with cheers, possibly of the "Way to let 'er rip, bro!" variety.
> As it happens, the gas turns out to be unnaturally rank, and adulation quickly turns to gasps, frowns ("nostrils flared, each face curled slightly in a frown"), and a panic to escape the toxic bloom. Your once formidable accomplishment is now "going down" in history: "*Hey, do you guys remember the day that Peter ripped that absolutely nasty...*"
> "So try to banish this disgrace, light a candle, wave a fan." Maybe you can diffuse it or blow it up or something. *Sweet mercy, what did you eat, Pete!? Oh f... Where's the Febreeze? I'm gonna pass out.*
> "Smear with incense, hide your face, or get out early, while you can."

Comment: And the location? A lift? ^^

Comment: Yes! and @MartinBüttner, that is the location I had in mind too! Well done to you both!

Answer (score 7):

> The beast is a [duplicate] question.
> Most duplicates are popular, classic puzzles. Puzzlers post them because they're fundamentally just good puzzles people want to share with the world. And initially, since most readers don't realize they're duplicates, they're met with great enthusiasm: many answers ("a wild cacophony of sound") and upvotes ("applause, a jovial shout should be the least").
> But inevitably, after some quick checks ("fleeting glances"), the comments start to appear: "*Possible duplicate of...*", "*This has already been posted at...*" and jubilation turns to resentment ("nostrils flared, each face curled slightly in a frown").
> A duplicate question. It must be destroyed and the poster punished. This is the StackExchange code that we, "all who share the journey", all know well.
> And so with a heavy heart, we dutifully slay the beast, downvoting it ("the beast is also going down") until, after one last whimpering cry, nothing remains.

Comment: Very nice answer! This fits pretty well, but isn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Is it...

> The Sun? Animals wake when the Sun rises. The Sun also sets.